# Nested signup form does not render correctly after invalid submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a combined/nested signup form, which registers a new organization plus a member (two models with a 1:many relationship).

When submitting invalid information to the form (that is, I fill in invalid info for the organization and no info at all for the member) it should render the combined signup form again with the error message. **Instead in this scenario after submitting the invalid information, it only renders the part of the signup form for signing up the organization (without the member part of the form).** If I enter invalid information for both organization and member, then it does render correctly the full combined form.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with the code?

---

The **controller** includes:

```
  def new
    if (logged_in?)
      flash[:danger] = "You're already logged in"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
    @organization = Organization.new
    @member = @organization.members.build
  end

  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params)
    if @organization.save
      @organization.members.each do |single_member|
        single_member.send_activation_email
      end
      flash[:success] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else                            
      render 'new'    # This is the relevant render line.
    end
  end
```

**The new view:**

```
<%= render partial: "registrationform", locals: { url: organizations_path } %>
```

**The partial (registrationform):**

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :url %>

  <%= form_for @organization, url: url do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <h4>Details of the organization:</h4>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.fields_for :members do |p| %>
      <h4>Your personal details:</h4>
      <%= p.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= p.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= p.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  <% end %>

<% else %>
  <%= flash.now[:danger] = "Error: no url defined" %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes:**

```
get 'signup/organization' => 'organizations#new', as: 'register'
```

Comment: please show your `#new` method on the controller

Comment: I added `def new` and also one of the routes, which might be related to the cause...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new action, you are doing `@organization.members.build`, which is not in your edit action. When the validation fails, it will render your new action, but won't run your new action. You could try putting `@organization.members.build` in the else clause of your `create` action like:

```
else
  @organization.members.build if @organization.members.blank?
  render 'new'
end
```